# Random FLOAT number between 1 and 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I know how I would do this with int numbers and with floats between 0 and 1.0.

```
import random 
my_number = random.randrange(0,11)
print(my_number)

import random
my_number = random.random()
print(my_number)
```

but what about floats above 1... say 1.0 and 10.0??